# Angular directive and Jquery slideToggle function implementation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slide, slidetoggle, angularjs-directive

Using angular and jquery I implemented slideToggle function. In order to only apply this function to one specific HTML element, I am using within ng-click function one parameter, my code works fine but, I want to know if exists another better way to implement directives and ng-click functions in angular:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" ng-click="toggle('first')" value="Toggle First">
        <input type="button" ng-click="toggle('second')" value="Toggle Second">
        <input type="button" ng-click="toggle('third')" value="Toggle third">
        <div class="div1" section="first" toggle="first" >
            <p>This is section #1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div1" toggle="second">
            <p>This is another section #1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="div1" toggle="third">
            <p>This is 3 section #1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
.div1 {
    background: Brown;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div1 p {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

**directives.js**

```
angular.module("myApp", []) //
    .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.toggle = function(section) {
            console.log('<toggle function> section :' + section);
            $scope.section = section;
            $scope.$broadcast('event:toggle');
        }
    }) //
    .directive('toggle', function() {
        return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$on('event:toggle', function() {
                if(attrs.toggle == scope.section){
                    elem.slideToggle('fast');
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

One concern of my own is the way that I am communicating between directive and scope:

```
        $scope.section = section;
```

and

```
        if(attrs.toggle == scope.section){
```

I will appreciate any advice for a better Angular implementation.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to keep your controller clean you could set up a service which handles your toggled containers or you can add a custom id to each broadcasted event like $broadcast('toggle'+something).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Plunker Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/u69puq?p=preview

FYI, at the time of writing, the AngularJS team are adding an [*ngAnimate*](https://twitter.com/yearofmoo/status/308745628010295296) directive which will (hopefully) offer most of the animate functionality that jQuery currently offers, e.g. Slide, Fade etc, which is sorely missing at the moment IMO.

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainController">      
    <input type="button" value="Toggle First" ng-click="box1=!box1">
    <input type="button" value="Toggle Second" ng-click="box2=!box2">
    <input type="button" value="Toggle third" ng-click="box3=!box3">

    <div class="div1" data-slide-toggle="box1" data-slide-toggle-duration="100" >
        <p>This is section #1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div2" data-slide-toggle="box2" data-slide-toggle-duration="2000">
        <p>This is another section #1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div3" data-slide-toggle="box3">
        <p>This is 3 section #1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.box1 = $scope.box2 = $scope.box3 = true;
});

myApp.directive('slideToggle', function() {  
  return {
    restrict: 'A',      
    scope:{
      isOpen: "=slideToggle"
    },  
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var slideDuration = parseInt(attr.slideToggleDuration, 10) || 200;      
      scope.$watch('isOpen', function(newVal,oldVal){
        if(newVal !== oldVal){ 
          element.stop().slideToggle(slideDuration);
        }
      });
    }
  };  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think my original concern remains, you can note that the parameter for function toggle('first') indicates which element must be showed or hidden. I wanna know if the way that this parameter is communicating with directive is correct.

Comment: @Osy: See updated comments, code and Plnkr demo. Should be more inline with what you were initially after.

Comment: According to AngularJs' documentation, "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat" : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit do you have any workaround here ?

Comment: @GFoley83 I found your code helpful in getting my form to toggle, but don't quite understand what is going on in it. Specifically why it is referenced as data-slide-toggle but named slideToggle. I'm new to angJS but haven't seen that syntax between the 2. Also, I don't understand most of the syntax in the directive and was wondering if you could message me comments for your code block?? The only lines I fully understand are the stuff in the controller and the element.stop() line. Sorry... I've been looking for this for days and I just want to understand how this gave me the behavior I wanted.

Comment: @clanier9 This is just an Angular convention. Directives are declared using camel case e.g. `thisIsMyDirective`. When you add the directive to your html you have to use snake case so if we stick with `thisIsMyDirective` this could be added to an element as `this-is-my-directive`, `data-this-is-my-directive`, `x-this-is-my-directive` etc. Basically wherever you have a capital letter in your directive js, that becomes a dash followed by small letter in your html.

Comment: @GFoley83 Thanks! super helpful. One last thing... what exactly are the isOpen pieces to this puzzle responsible for, and what are the newVal and oldVal?

Comment: @clanier9 My `slideToggle` directive is isolated so I've bound my open/closed bool variables (box1, box2, box3) from my controller to  my directive through `scope.isOpen`. That's what `scope:{ isOpen: "=slideToggle" }` means on my directive; bind my local scope variable called `isOpen` to whatever variable is passed into the html attribute called `slideToggle` (which becomes `data-slide-toggle` on our html. newVal, oldVal are standard in all watch functions. Basically I'm just watch for a new value.

Comment: @clanier9 Sounds like you're still getting your head around the basics. If I was you I'd go through the first two pages on egghead.io here: https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs?order=ASC Trust me, this will help clear a lot of things up for you.

Comment: @GFoley83 thanks. that makes a lot of sense. I will read through your link tomorrow.

Comment: Is it possible to use this with ng-repeat? Imagining solution using $index.

Answer (score 4):

*[@GFoley83](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654708/gfoley83) This helped me out a lot thanks! I'm a newbie, so not sure if this is the right way to add a suggestion to help, sorry if it's not. I'm also no expert, so i'm happy for my suggestion to be improved.*

I needed the item to start hidden and the ng-init didn't seem to do anything. So, I've added a fourth box with an attribute set to start hidden

Using the code @GFoley83 provided I have an additional attribute "start shown" added to the div which will be toggled.

```
 <input type="button" value="Toggle Fourth" ng-click="box4=!box4">
 <div class="div1" data-slide-toggle="box4" data-start-shown="false">
    <p>This is 4 section and starts hidden</p>
 </div>
```

The directive has also been updated and now has a check on this new attribute.If it's passed false, we'll hide - otherwise it will continue as before and start by showing the item.

```
     return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            isOpen: "=slideToggle"  // attribute
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var slideDuration = parseInt(attr.slideToggleDuration, 10) || 200;
            if (attr.startShown=="false") {
                element.hide();
            }
            scope.$watch('isOpen', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    element.stop().slideToggle(slideDuration);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Plunker updated : http://plnkr.co/edit/WB7UXK?p=preview

Comment: Glad to be of help! I removed the `ng-init`s; as @Charlesthk pointed out, it's generally bad practice to use them to initialise variables (though when using Angular with .NET web forms, they can be handy).

Answer (score 0):

After trying the solution of Peter i can see that directives below slideToggle cannot acces to parent scope. This is my solution.

```
evoapp.directive('slideToggle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false ,
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var slideDuration = parseInt(attr.slideToggleDuration, 10) || 200;
            var toggle = attr.toggle ;

            scope.$watch(toggle, function(newVal,oldVal){
                if(newVal !== oldVal){
                    element.stop().slideToggle(slideDuration);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```